# Blur a child image when hover on a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I have the code below, it's a list with images making a grid.
I want to set a css blur class to the image when hover over the entire "li". One of the solutions I've came up to is setting a class for every li and image (http://jsfiddle.net/Y85pZ/), but it's gonna be a long list, and I wanted something simpler, Javascript is OK.

I've think that maybe setting in JavaScript that when the "li" is hovered, it's child "img" element is set to blur(2px), but I have absolutely no idea of how to do that in JS. Any help?

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
<li><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /><div><h3>See &raquo</h3></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /><div><h3>See &raquo</h3></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /><div><h3>See &raquo</h3></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Wait, I'm confused... You currently have CSS in place to blur images when its parent `<li>` is hovered... What is it you're trying to do, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
.cbp-rfgrid li:hover img {
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do but if you are just trying to blur the img inside a list item on hover then the following code should work fine .

```
.cbp-rfgrid li:hover img{
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: Exactly that, but for some reason I couldn't get the first line of syntax in the correct order... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('img').css({blurstylehere})
})
```

It should help. Maybe logic should be somehow changed (not mouseover, maybe), but in general that's how it can be made.

To amenadiel's answer: I thought handling such things are not yet implemented.. Correct me please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not sure about the blur effect, I just answered on a css selector basis. My browser did blur the imgs tho.